# Any active harm in `if False in [a, b, c, d]`

Tags: python

Is there any active harm in using `if False in [a, b, c, d]`?

It reduces the size of the code and it works in the interpreter. But is there any active harm such a condition can cause?

Comment: Out of curiousity - what's your reason to ask this?

Comment: Alternatively: `if not all([a, b, c, d])`. What do you understand by "active harm" anyway?

Comment: @FelixKling That'd make more sense to me: but of course it's slightly different than `if False in [a, b, c, None]`

Comment: @Jon: Good point, I did not consider that...

Comment: Why do you think there is a possibility of *harm*?

Comment: Using a tuple rather than a list--`if False in (a, b, c, d)`--is faster (about 30% faster, based on my `timeit` results), incidentally.

Comment: Don't think so Though it may be better to use tuple instead of list.

Comment: @gorlum0 See for yourself: http://pastebin.com/TWJhwb3Y

Comment: The harm could have come from some implementation detail (a gotcha) of python that fails in this case. Just now, I learned to never let a 0 in that list (or anything else that needs to evaluate against `False)

Comment: @JoelCornett: It was comment on the question itself! And even saying the same as you did.

Comment: That's not "harm", that is a surprising, unexpected edge-case. "Harm" means things have been damaged, altered in a disruptive manner.

Comment: @gorlum0: Ohhh. haha. My apologies.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Nevermind, happens. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no harm in:

```
if False in [a, b, c, d]
```

It's more or less equivalent to:

```
for i in [a, b, c, d]:
    if i == False:
        return True
return False
```

but it checks for the presence of the literal `False` object only. It doesn't check for objects that are "falsy", i.e. they behave like `False` in an `if` condition. Examples of other values that are falsy are empty strings, empty lists or `None`.

See the docs for the details on that: [Truth value testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

If you just want to check whether a list contains any falsy element, instead use:

```
if not all([a, b, c, d])
```

which looks like:

```
for i in [a, b, c, d]:
    if not i:
        return True
return False
```

which is usually what you want.

Comment: if False in [a, b, c, d] doesn't check for literal `False`. `False in [0]` is True

Comment: @soulcheck As someone already wrote, `False` *is* `0`, while `None`, `[]`, `()` etc aren't.

Comment: @glglgl `False is 0` is False ;)

Comment: @soulcheck: I think @glglgl wasn't using `is` in the Python sense, but rather to mean "equals". `False == 0` will be true, while `False == []` is not.

Comment: @soulcheck I wrote *is*, not `is` :-)

Comment: @Blckknght i know what he meant, that's why it got smiley at the end

Answer (score 3):

No, there *normally* is no harm such a condition could cause.

The `in` comparison operator doesn't alter anything. If any of the variables `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` is indeed `0` or `False`, then the test would succeed, otherwise it would fail (return `False`). The four variables collected (temporarily) into a list would not be affected themselves.

(Why `0`? Because `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `False == 0` is `True` in python. So `False in [0]` is `True` as well. Try it out in your interpreter; `issubclass(bool, int)` returns `True`, and then try `True + 1` for more surprises).

The one exception would be if someone had made the mistake of creating a `__eq__` equality hook on a custom class that *altered* the state of the instance. That would be a big bug in that custom class, not anything specific to the `in` statement itself.

Answer (score 2):

`False in [0,0,0]` returns true even though there's no actual `False` in the list (although as commenters noted `0 == False` ).

If you care about that kind of things, you'll have to check for object identity with:

```
any(x is False for x in [a, b, c, d])
```

Comment: No, `False` is a subclass of int, and thus `False == 0` is True. `False in [None]` fails.

Comment: This isn't actually coercion.  `[]` is a "false" value, but `False in [[]]` is `False`.  What is happening here is that `False == 0`... because booleans are integers.  You will also find that `True in [1]`, because `True == 1`.

Comment: Does Python even have coercion? It's strongly typed, unlike JS for instance